# Redirect marked network packets to specific interface using iptables

Tags: networking, router, iptables

I'm developing application which connects to specific websocket endpoint (port 80). Application is behind Teltonika RUTX12 with two SIM cards. I am trying to configure this router in a way that traffic between my application and remote ws endpoint goes only through SIM 2 interface. So, I tried to mark network packets and then to apply the ipv4 rule, but no success. Application is running on single PC (192.168.1.10). Router GW is 192.168.1.1.
Both SIM cards gets dynamic IP addresses.

I am marking packets using this cmd:

`iptables -I PREROUTING -t mangle -d <remote_endpoint_ip> -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 79`

I am setting routing table with specific ID (IP table field of SIM 2 interface is set to the same ID). After that I had created advanced static rule, which based on mark 79, redirects traffic to outgoing interface - SIM 2). But this doesnt work and still all traffic goes through SIM 1.

Also, can I use only iptables for this or I have to rely on Teltonika WEBUI?

Thanks in advance